# Не могу открыть склонированный проект с githab.com в NetBeans IDE

Tags: java, github, netbeans

Здравствуйте. Собственно по сабжу: нужно склонировать проект с мастера к себе ну и запустить его.
Делаю все так: в панели меню IDE выбираю **Группа -> Git -> Клонировать**, ввожу адрес репозитория с логином и паролем, выбираю папку, в которую он будет склонирован, ветка - master и немного жду. Выскакивает окно, название которого "Клонирование завершено", в окне есть две кнопки: **создать проект** и **закрыть окно**.

1. При нажатии на первую кнопку я создавал "Проект Java с существующими исходными файлами" и указывал папку, в которую я клонировал файлы с гита. В этом случае создаются новый файл **nbbuild.xml** и папка **nbdist**, так как они уже существуют под такими же именами, но без приставки **nb**, а склонированные файлы не видны вовсе. Есть только папка Библиотеки.
2. При закрытии окна и попытке открыть проект, NetBeans не видит папку со склонированными файлами как проект и соответственно открыть их я не могу.

Я пробовал сначала создать проект и пустой, и обычный, а потом в него клонировать с гита, но результат тот же. Кстати, я смотрел пару видео по данному поводу и на них, после клонирования была кнопка открыть проект, а не создать, как у меня.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно решить эту проблему. Заранее благодарю.

Comment: я в идеи работаю. новый проект написан в бинсе, у них с идеей структура проектов разная, нужно её сохранить

Comment: структура может быть любой независимо от ide

Comment: @StrangerintheQ правильно сказал, проект не должен быть привязан к какой-либо из IDE

Comment: ок, склонируйте проект созданный в идее нетбинсом. другое дело, когда коммитятся только файлы .java а не весь проект

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Решено:** на гит не была залита папка build, поэтому проект и не открывало.

Answer (score 0):

Использую netbeans с php, но думаю с java будет примерно также.

- Если конфигурационные файлы netbeans сохранены в репозитории, то после клонирования появится окошко с кнопкой "открыть проект".
- Если конфигурационные файлы netbeans НЕ сохранены в репозитории, то после клонирования нужно нажать кнопку "создать проект", и далее делать так как будто создаёшь **пустой** проект, указывая директорию куда был склонирован репозиторий.

Comment: пустой проект подразумевает создание конфигурационных файлов. в первом посте описано, что такое действие не подошло.